# How do you reverse a Reopen vote?

Tags: discussion

I voted to reopen a question, but thinking about the answer, I realize it is still too broad and so wanted to change my vote.  Is there a way to do so?  Or do I just have to count on others to keep it closed?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently reopen votes [can't be retracted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/162102), even after it became possible to retract a close vote.  (The link is to an unanswered feature request on Meta.SE.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I'll have to be more careful in the future.